# Returning Nested Objects on .NET API using OData

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate, odata

I am working on a .NET API that uses OData and I am currently having issues returning nested objects back to the client.

Everything seems to be working, even if I put a break point on the Controller just before the response. I can see the Vendor object that is going to be returned with all the info has populated correctly, but when I look at the JSON response the Client received it only has primitive types and enums, every other property that is another object does not get serialized to the JSON result.

```
public class Vendor : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual VendorAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string VendorName { get; set; }
}

public class VendorAddress : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

}

 public class Address : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }   
    public virtual string Line1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Line2 { get; set; }     
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string County { get; set; }
    public virtual string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }    
}   

 public SingleResult<Vendor> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var result = _repository.Query<Vendor>().Where(a => a.Id == key);
    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

Basically I want to return the Vendor info including the PrimaryAddress/Address information on the JSON result but can't seem to figure out how to.

Comment: do you derive from `ODataController`? What is `_repository`? Also try to remove `virtual` from the property that is not loading

Comment: @Alonso: you wrote .NET API. I guess you mean ASP.NET Web API, right ?!

Comment: @jpq: Yeah its an ASP.NET API

Comment: @T.S. I did derived from ODataController, all other OData query url stuff like $count, $select and others seem to be working properly. Cant remove virtual cause as far as I know they are required for working with NHibernate

Comment: I think, I know where your problem is. I just wrote service like this against entity framework. In EF all I need to do it setup model relation properly. I don't see, for example, where is relationship between your models? Here is the hocus-pocus  - OData uses same attribute classes as entity framework. If you set those attributes (like `[Key]`, `[ForeignKey]`) on your models, Odata model builder will create all needed relationships and your JSON will come ok. Or you can map them using fluent Odata syntax. In my case because I set mappings in models for EF, OData worked without special mappings

Answer (score 2):

`VendorAddress` and `Address` are so called Navigation Properties.
You can get them by using `$expand` on your query.
First add a [EnableQuery] to your Get method

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Vendor> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
```

then try a request in the form

```
<serviceUri>/Vendor(1)?$expand=VendorAddress
<serviceUri>/Vendor(1)?$expand=VendorAddress($expand=Address)
```

you'll have to add the line

```
config.Expand()
```

in your

```
WebApiConfig.Register(HTTPConfiguration config)
```

method.

Here is a example request on a test service:

http://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People('russellwhyte')?$expand=BestFriend($expand=Trips)

and some more information for reference: http://www.odata.org/odata-services/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help so far, however I'm still struggling with this :(. I added code[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 3)]code on the Controller call and also I managed to expand the first Navigation Property but not using <serviceUri>/Vendor(1)?$expand=primaryAddress but instead I did it using <serviceUri>/api/v2/odata/Vendors?&$select=id,vendorName,primaryAddress&$expand=primaryAddress, from this request I get the id property but can't seem to expand the other Navigation inside primaryAddress to actually get the Address info I need

Comment: ok, can you check $expand=PrimaryAddress/Address instead of $expand=PrimaryAddress($expand=Address)